# Android recycler view with checkbox issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in my `MainActivity` with an `adapter class`. Each List cell of `RecyclerView` contains a `Checkbox`. One preselect value is set for the `Checkbox`. If it is true `Checkbox` is set checked. One more thing is some of the items are exclusively allowed for single selection(ie, if i select those items' `Checkbox`, other checked boxes will get unchecked). That value is determined by another parameter in the each item dictionary. And also i have a button in my activity, when nothing is selected button will get disabled, vice versa. How can i implement these features? My classes is given below.

```
public class FurtherExtrasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FurtherExtrasAdapter.ViewHolder> {


ArrayList<Item> items;
Context context;
int flag = 0;
private CouponCodeActivity mThis;

public FurtherExtrasAdapter(ArrayList<Item> items, CouponCodeActivity mThis, Context context) {
    this.items = items;
    this.mThis = mThis;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cell_platform_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    ;
    holder.enrolment.setText(items.get(position).getName());
    holder.selectEnrollment.setChecked(items.get(position).isPreselect());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView enrolment;
    CheckBox selectEnrollment;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        enrolment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_entrollment);
        selectEnrollment = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_select_entrollment);


    }
}}
```

**And my view class contains below codes.**

```
  rv_further=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_further);
  rv_further.setLayoutManager(manager);
            rv_further.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rv_further.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rv_further.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv_further.setAdapter(adapter);

 public void updateButtonState(double num) {

    checkedBoxs += num;

        if (checkedBoxs > 0) {
            Log.d("---CHECKED",String.valueOf(checkedBoxs));
            btnApply.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Log.d("---UNCHECKED",String.valueOf(checkedBoxs));
            btnApply.setEnabled(false);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use check clicklistener like...

```
holder.selectEnrollment .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            items.get(position).setPreselect(!items.get(position).isPreselect);
        }
    });
```

Comment: But how about controlling exclusivity?

Comment: what. you exact want...?

Comment: 1. Button in the activity should update according to user clicks on the checkbox. if nothing is selected, button should disable. 2.for some of the items in recycler view, one exclusivity boolean variable is der. if it is true, then we can check/select only that checkbutton. others should unselect automatically.

Comment: then set checkbox.setenable(false);    or checkbox.setcheck(true/false);

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:

> then we can check/select only that checkbutton. others should unselect automatically.

You can keep a variable in your adapter, say

```
int position_last_selected = -1;
```

Then when you add, check if this value is -1 or not. if not, get the item for the position,

```
list.get(position_last_selected).setIsPreSelect(false);
// then update your current position item
list.get(position).setIsPreSelect(true);
// update the last selected value
position_last_selected = position;
//Update the adapter
notifiyDataSetChanged();
```

Try it out!